# How to have condition in ActiveRecord update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to update  a record. Am using the following code.

```
Proddiscount.update({:prodid => params[:id]}, {:discount=>params[:discount]})
```

Query Im trying to have is:

```
update proddiscount set discount = '' where prodid = ''
```

Comment: Is prodid you primary key? Or are there many proddiscounts with `prodid = some_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

If prodif is not a primary key, use `update_all` (read more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002273))

```
Proddiscount.update_all("discount = #{params[:discount]}", ["prodid = ?", params[:prodid])
```

But it won't trigger validations.

Answer (score -2):

How about doing this:

```
@prod = Proddiscount.find(:first, :conditions => {prodid => params[:id]})
@prod.update_attributes({:discount=>params[:discount]})
```

Comment: It kinda depends on what "prodid" exactly is, like asked @klew